# Kotlin - Type inference failed for findViewById

Tags: android, kotlin, google-places-api, type-inference, kotlin-android-extensions

i'm trying to access the `setOnClickListener` method of the clear button that comes from Google's Place Autocomplete API `R.id.place_autocomplete_clear_button`.

i found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54434944/5076153): but i get the error stated in the title

`placeAutocompleteFragment?.view?.findViewById(R.id.place_autocomplete_clear_button)`

---

I know in Kotlin you can apply the:

`apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'`

and then import it in the working class:

`import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_add_location.*`

I've tried `R.id.place_autocomplete_clear_button.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener{...`

but no luck, unresolved reference: setOnClickListener

---

**EDIT**

i've done the follow, but get a NPE:

> kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
>           at com.example.khoi.parkingapp.fragments.AddLocationFragment.clearButton(AddLocationFragment.kt:129)

with the following code:

```
private fun clearButton() {
    placeAutocompleteFragment!!.view!!.findViewById<View>(R.id.place_autocomplete_clear_button)!!
        .setOnClickListener {
            object : View.OnClickListener {
                override fun onClick(v: View?) {
                    println("cleared")
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Drop `R.id.` and try `place_autocomplete_clear_button.setOnClickListener(..`

Comment: If you have `import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_add_location.*` "acting correctly" then just use `place_autocomplete_clear_button.setOnClickListener {...}`

Comment: @forpas still not working, `Unresolved reference: place_autocomplete_clear_button`. i know the extension is working though because i'm using it for my other elements from my fragment's layout

Comment: If you have other views from `fragment_add_location` referenced without  problem and `place_autocomplete_clear_button` is defined in this layout but not working then you're doing something wrong. Maybe misspelled the button?

Comment: @forpas `place_autocomplete_clear_button ` isn't defined in that layout.  "Place autocomplete API" has a clear button so i do not need to create a clear button. I just want to listen to response when the user click the clear button. Here is a picture of that button https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAWif.jpg

Comment: @forpas i'm tyring to implement the code from the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54434834/how-to-build-a-listener-to-listen-to-clear-button-event-for-place-autocomplete-a